# How to safely drop nothing from a vector when the negative index could be integer(0)?

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a vector `x = 1:10`, and it is constructed by concatenating two other vectors `a = integer(0)` and `b = 1:10` together (this is an edge case). I want to split up the combined vector again into `a` and `b` later on. I would have thought I could safely separate them with:

```
i = seq_along(a)
x[i]
x[-i]
```

But I discovered that when I use `x[-integer(0)]` I get `integer(0)` returned, instead of `x` itself as I naively thought. What is the best way to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use negative indexing and the index may degenerate to `integer(0)` (for example, the index is computed from `which`), pad a large "out-of-bound" value to the index. Removing an "out-of-bound" value has no side effect.

```
x <- 1:10
i <- integer(0)
x[-c(i, 11)]  ## position 11 is "out-of-bound"
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If you bother setting this "out-of-bound" value, here is a canonical choice: `2 ^ 31`, because this value has exceeded representation range of 32-bit signed integer, yet it is not `Inf`.

---

An alternative way is to do an `if` test on `length(i)`. For example:

```
if (length(i)) x[-i] else x
```

**Caution:** don't use function `ifelse` for this purpose.