# Why does y[-which(x)] return a length-0 vector if which(x) is length 0?

Tags: r

```
letters[-which(letters %in% c('a', 'b'))]
```

This returns c-z, dropping 'a' and 'b'

```
letters[-which(letters %in% letters)]
```

This returns character(), as expected, you're dropping the entire vector

```
letters[-which(letters %in% LETTERS)]
```

I'd think this would return letters, but it returns character(). This behavior is predictable but its super annoying if you forget about it. Why does R do this? Could a special operator be created that would return the complete vector instead of a 0-length vector?

edit: here's a more complex example trying `setdiff`

```
df <- data.frame(letters, LETTERS, c(letters[1:13], LETTERS[14:26]), stringsAsFactors = F)
head(df)
df[-which(df[, 2] %in% df[, 3]), 1] # Retuns a-m
df[-which(df[, 1] %in% df[, 3]), 1] # Returns n-z
df[-which(df[, 2] %in% df[, 1]), 1] # Returns character()

df[which(setdiff(df[, 2], df[, 3]) %in% df[, 2]), 1] # Returns a-m
df[which(setdiff(df[, 1], df[, 3]) %in% df[, 1]), 1] # Also returns a-m
df[which(setdiff(df[, 3], df[, 1]) %in% df[, 1]), 1] # character()
df[which(setdiff(df[, 3], df[, 1]) %in% df[, 3]), 1] # a-m
df[which(setdiff(df[, 1], df[, 3]) %in% df[, 3]), 1] # character()
```

Comment: this is one of my least favourite things about R tbh. It's because `which(letters %in% LETTERS)` returns `integer(0)`, so you are selecting `letters[integer(0)]` which R doesn't really handle very well. I agree it would make way more sense to return the whole vector

Comment: its really infuriating, isn't it? i usually wrap subsets like that in an ifelse to head it off, but i'd like to just write a generalized operator to use instead

Comment: It's confusing but as @RAB notes, it makes sense when you consider how `which(letters %in% LETTERS)` evaluates. I guess `setdiff(letters, LETTERS)` is the operation to return what you expect.

Comment: [How to safely drop nothing from a vector when the negative index could be integer(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52772380/4891738)

Answer (score 4):

`-which(letters %in% LETTERS)` returns `integer(0)` and when you subset that `letters[-which(letters %in% LETTERS)]` it returns `character(0)` which is logical but yes, it can be annoying if we do not pay proper attention.

You can avoid that by using `setdiff` instead

```
setdiff(letters, c('a', 'b'))
#[1] "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v"
#[21] "w" "x" "y" "z"

setdiff(letters, letters)
#character(0)

setdiff(letters, LETTERS)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t"
#[21] "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

PS - However, make sure you have the correct order in `setdiff`, `setdiff(x, y)` is not equal to `setdiff(y, x)`.

Comment: i tried out `setdiff` in the above example but im not sure im going about it correctly? i cant get it to spit out the second half of the filtered vector

Comment: @brandonEm If I understood you correctly, I think you are applying `setdiff` in wrong way. The three equivalent of your `which` function using `setdiff` would be `df[df[, 2] %in% setdiff(df[, 2], df[, 3]) , 1]`, `df[df[, 1] %in% setdiff(df[, 1], df[, 3]), 1]` and `df[df[, 2] %in% setdiff(df[, 2], df[, 1]), 1]` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think R should return `letters`?

`-which(letters %in% LETTERS)` is the negation of `which(letters %in% LETTERS)`. So you should get nothing.  `-which(everything)` is equivalent to nothing. Removing `letters` from `letters` leaves you with an empty character vector. I think the result is appropriate in this situation.

As for code that could return the entire vector instead of the zero-length vector, you could use an `if()` statement in a function.

```
w <- -which(letters %in% letters)
if (!length(out <- letters[w])) letters else out
```