# Speed up setdiff(), intersect(), union() operations on vectors in R

Tags: r, performance, datatable

I have a data table `dt1`:

| id1 | id2 | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | c(1, 2, 3, 4) | c(1, 3, 6) |
| 2 | b | c(2, 6, 9, 8) | c(8, 5) |

I want to add new columns which are the result of the `setdiff()`, `intersect()` and `union()` operations on the `V1` and `V2` variables.

Expected output:

| id1 | id2 | V1 | V2 | diff_V1_V2 | intersect_V1_V2 | union_V1_V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | c(1, 2, 3, 4) | c(1, 3, 6) | c(2, 4) | c(1, 3) | c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6) |
| 2 | b | c(2, 6, 9, 8) | c(8, 5) | c(2, 6, 9) | c(8) | c(2, 5, 6, 8, 9) |

I tried:

```
dt_new <- dt1[, c("diff_V1_V2", "intersect_V1_V2", "union_V1_V2") := list(
              Map(setdiff, V1, V2),
              Map(intersect, V1, V2),
              Map(union, V1, V2))]
```

But my real vectors are very long, so these operations take a very long time.

So, how can these operations be sped up or how to get similar results using another functions/approaches? I'm looking for the most efficient way.
Or is it possible to parallelize calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naive approach:

```
Naive <- function (a, b) {
  list(intersect = intersect(a, b),
       union = union(a, b),
       adiffb = setdiff(a, b))
}
```

You can exploit basic mathematics to complete all three operations in one scan of vectors `a` and `b`, instead of three scans by three function calls. In addition, you can skip the expensive `unique` if you know for sure that there are no duplicated values in either vector.

```
SetOp <- function (a, b, no.dup.guaranteed = FALSE) {
  if (no.dup.guaranteed) {
    au <- a
    bu <- b
  } else {
    au <- unique(a)
    bu <- unique(b)
  }
  ind <- match(bu, au, nomatch = 0)
  INTERSECT <- au[ind]
  DIFF <- au[-c(ind, length(au) + 1)]  ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/52772380
  UNION <- c(bu, DIFF)
  list(intersect = INTERSECT, union = UNION, adiffb = DIFF)
}

SetOp(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b = c(1, 3, 6))
SetOp(a = c(2, 6, 9, 8), b = c(8, 5))
```

Some benchmark:

```
## no duplicated values in either a or b; can set no.dup.guaranteed = TRUE
a <- sample.int(11000, size = 10000, replace = FALSE)
b <- sample.int(11000, size = 10000, replace = FALSE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(naive = Naive(a, b),
                               better = SetOp(a, b),
                               fly = SetOp(a, b, no.dup.guaranteed = TRUE))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  naive 6.457302 6.489710 6.751996 6.511399 6.567941 8.571623   100
# better 3.251701 3.268873 3.377910 3.277086 3.306723 3.880755   100
#    fly 1.734898 1.749300 1.805163 1.755927 1.767114 3.326179   100

## lots of duplicated values in both a and b; must have no.dup.guaranteed = FALSE
a <- sample.int(100, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample.int(100, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(naive = Naive(a, b),
                               better = SetOp(a, b))
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#  naive 1421.702 1431.023 1653.1339 1443.147 1483.255 3809.031   100
# better  396.193  398.695  446.7062  400.293  412.046 1995.294   100
```

If you want further speedup, you need to think about how to speed up `unique()`. This is not easy, because you probably can't beat the internal algorithms used by **R**.

---

> I see additional speed improvement replacing unique() with the R fast `Rfast::sort_unique()`.

Thank you, @[M.Viking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10276092/m-viking). It is nice to see [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633572/4891738). I have not got time to install GNU Scientific Library (GSL) on my operation system so haven’t been able to install and try **Rfast** myself.

Here are some comments on your benchmark result.

- The reason why “better2” is faster than “fly”, is because `match` is faster on sorted vectors. So yes, even if there are no duplicated values in `a` and `b`, it is still a good idea to apply `sort_unique`.
- You may also want to try the `Match` function from **Rfast**. I spotted this function in the package's documentation, but don't know how fast it is compared with **R**'s base version. Also, the documentation does not state clearly how `Match` handles no-match. By contrast, the base version `match` has a useful argument `nomatch` which I set to 0 to avoid NA indexing.

> Good ideas. Unfortunately `Rfast::Match()` is not a drop in replacement for `base::match()`. However, luckily, `fastmatch::fmatch()` is a fast drop in replacement for `match()`.

We are having a really inspiring iteration here! That is good to know! Amazing **R** community with so many useful tools!

---

> My `V1` and `V2` variables do not contain duplicates, so there is no need to use the `unique` function, if I understand correctly?

Intuitively, yes, because we don't want to do extra work. But interestingly, the benchmark result in [M.Viking's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72633572/4891738) shows that it is worth sorting vectors to speedup `match`. So you may actually take the `SetOp2()` given by M.Viking.

I don't think `SetOp3()` with `base::match` replaced by `fastmatch::fmatch` worthwhile in your application. According to its documentation, `fmatch` is faster than `match` only when we perform repeated matching like `match(a, key)`, `match(b, key)`, etc., where `key` is reused. The benchmark by M.Viking favors this, because `microbenchmark()` repeats `SetOp3(a, b)` for 100 times. In the first run, `fmatch` is as fast as `match`; then it is much faster than `match` in the following 99 runs. In your application, however, each vector is used only once. Since no reuse exists, we are good to stay with `match`.

> So, how can I apply your solution to each row of my data (`V1` and `V2` are lists there)?

We have to use a loop or loop-like function, like the `Map` you used in your question. The only issue is that we need some post-processing to extract the results. See below.

```
V1 <- list(a1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), a2 = c(2, 6, 9, 8))
V2 <- list(b1 = c(1, 3, 6), b2 = c(8, 5))

## or: ans <- Map(SetOp2, V1, V2)
ans <- Map(SetOp, V1, V2, no.dup.guaranteed = TRUE)
## post-processing
INTERSECT <- lapply(ans, "[[", 1)
UNION <- lapply(ans, "[[", 2)
SETDIFF <- lapply(ans, "[[", 3)
```

---

**Additional thoughts on parallel processing**

[jblood94's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72636589/4891738) takes a further step by parallel computing. Good job! It is a great exercise for practicing `parallel`. Yet in principle, we don't want to parallel this task, because it is memory-bound rather than CPU-bound. We are just scanning data from memory without doing sophisticated CPU arithmetic. It is known that parallel processing is not promising for this kind of job and I don't expect a big speedup. It seems that *jblood94* is able to get 82.89 / 34.21 = 2.42 speedup against serial processing. However, he/she does not mention how many CPU cores are used. For example, if 8 cores are exploited, then 2.42 speedup is pretty poor.

Answer (score 3):

A version of @Zheyuan Li answer benchmarked using `Rfast::sort_unique()` and `fastmatch::fmatch()`

```
#install.packages("Rfast")  ## Takes time to compile all the Rfast functions https://github.com/RfastOfficial/Rfast
library(Rfast)
#install.packages("fastmatch") ## https://github.com/s-u/fastmatch
library(fastmatch)

SetOp2 <- function (a, b, no.dup.guaranteed = FALSE) {
  if (no.dup.guaranteed) {
    au <- a
    bu <- b
  } else {
    au <- sort_unique(a) #Only difference from @Zheyuan Li version
    bu <- sort_unique(b) #""
  }
  ind <- match(bu, au, nomatch = 0)
  INTERSECT <- au[ind]
  DIFF <- au[-c(ind, length(au) + 1)]
  UNION <- c(bu, DIFF)
  list(intersect = INTERSECT, union = UNION, adiffb = DIFF)
}

SetOp3 <- function (a, b, no.dup.guaranteed = FALSE) {
  if (no.dup.guaranteed) {
    au <- a
    bu <- b
  } else {
    au <- sort_unique(a)  ## Updated
    bu <- sort_unique(b)  ## Updated
  }
  ind <- fastmatch::fmatch(bu, au, nomatch = 0)   ## Updated
  INTERSECT <- au[ind]
  DIFF <- au[-c(ind, length(au) + 1)]
  UNION <- c(bu, DIFF)
  list(intersect = INTERSECT, union = UNION, adiffb = DIFF)
}

a <- sample.int(11000, size = 10000, replace = FALSE)
b <- sample.int(11000, size = 10000, replace = FALSE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(naive = Naive(a, b),
                               better = SetOp(a, b),
                               better2 = SetOp2(a, b),
                               better3 = SetOp3(a, b),
                               fly = SetOp(a, b, no.dup.guaranteed = TRUE),
                               times=10000)
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
>    naive 2970.053 3110.7045 3409.1796 3215.7650 3352.5110 396391.39 10000
>   better 1749.386 1819.7195 1987.1681 1877.7340 1984.3705  39385.95 10000
>  better2  840.537  873.3440  977.6893  902.5495  969.4585  35723.44 10000
>  better3  421.832  460.3975  530.7420  480.0845  519.7660  38398.51 10000
>      fly  935.782  972.0125 1074.5115  993.6900 1062.4290  39954.88 10000
> ```

```
x <- sample.int(100, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample.int(100, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(naive = Naive(x, y),
                               better = SetOp(x, y),
                               better2 = SetOp2(x, y),
                               better3 = SetOp3(x, y),
                               times=10000)
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>     expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
>    naive 595.526 623.245 771.52724 654.2590 718.4740 38635.977 10000
>   better 188.642 196.369 255.91779 206.0725 227.1735 41866.460 10000
>  better2  54.856  59.675  71.53553  63.6070  74.8945   549.182 10000
>  better3  63.609  70.503  94.74702  80.8270 100.8745 25584.469 10000
> ```

*Nota Bene:* R version 4.0.4 compiled with `-mtune=native -march=native -O3 -fopenmp -fpic`, and openblas BLAS/LAPACK.

Comment: Good ideas. Unfortunately `Rfast::Match()` is not a drop in replacement for `base::match()`. However, luckily, `fastmatch::fmatch()` is a fast drop in replacement for `match()`.

Comment: I agree. Speed optimization is more fun than code golf!

Answer (score 2):

A parallelization approach building off @Zheyuan Li's answer (updated with `fastmatch::fmatch`):

```
library(data.table)
library(Rfast)
library(parallel)
library(fastmatch)

SetOp <- function(V1, V2) {
  n <- length(V1)
  DIFF <- vector("list", n)
  INTERSECT <- vector("list", n)
  UNION <- vector("list", n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    u1 <- sort_unique(V1[[i]])
    u2 <- sort_unique(V2[[i]])
    ind <- fmatch(u2, u1, nomatch = 0)
    DIFF[[i]] <- u1[-c(ind, length(u1) + 1)]
    INTERSECT[[i]] <- u1[ind]
    UNION[[i]] <- c(u2, DIFF[[i]])
  }
  
  list(DIFF, INTERSECT, UNION)
}

SetOpParallel <- function(V1, V2, ncl = detectCores() - 1L) {
  ncl <- min(length(V1), ncl)
  cl <- makeCluster(ncl)
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
  node <- rep(c(1:ncl, ncl:1), ceiling(length(V1)/ncl/2))[1:length(V1)][rank(-as.numeric(lengths(V1))*as.numeric(lengths(V2)), ties.method = "first")]
  clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(data.table); library(Rfast)})
  rowidx <- integer(length(V1))
  lastidx <- 0L
  for (i in 1:ncl) {
    # pass only the needed data to each node
    nodeidx <- which(node == i)
    rowidx[nodeidx] <- (lastidx + 1L):(lastidx + length(nodeidx))
    lastidx <- lastidx + length(nodeidx)
    v1 <- V1[nodeidx]
    v2 <- V2[nodeidx]
    clusterExport(cl[i], c("v1", "v2"), environment())
  }
  rm("v1", "v2")
  clusterExport(cl, "SetOp")
  rbindlist(clusterEvalQ(cl, SetOp(v1, v2)))[rowidx]
}
```

A smaller data set to check equivalency of the two functions:

```
n <- 1e2L
dt <- data.table(id1 = 1:n,
                 id2 = n:1,
                 V1 = replicate(n, sample.int(1e5, sample(5e4:6e4)), FALSE),
                 V2 = replicate(n, sample.int(1e5, sample(3e4:4e4)), FALSE))
identical(copy(dt)[, c("diff_V1_V2", "intersect_V1_V2", "union_V1_V2") := SetOp(V1, V2)],
          copy(dt)[, c("diff_V1_V2", "intersect_V1_V2", "union_V1_V2") := SetOpParallel(V1, V2)])
#> [1] TRUE
```

A much larger data set for speed comparison (using 15 cores):

```
n <- 1e4L
dt <- data.table(id1 = 1:n,
                 id2 = n:1,
                 V1 = replicate(n, sample.int(1e5, sample(5e4:6e4)), FALSE),
                 V2 = replicate(n, sample.int(1e5, sample(3e4:4e4)), FALSE))
dt2 <- copy(dt)
system.time(dt[, c("diff_V1_V2", "intersect_V1_V2", "union_V1_V2") := SetOpParallel(V1, V2)])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    6.08    9.31   34.68
rm(dt)
invisible(gc())
system.time(dt2[, c("diff_V1_V2", "intersect_V1_V2", "union_V1_V2") := SetOp(V1, V2)])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   35.25    8.37   45.16
```

Comment: FYI, I am not getting expected results from these functions. eg `SetOp(V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), V2 = c(1, 3, 6))`

Comment: @M.Viking, the functions are expecting lists of vectors for `V1` and `V2` as in the OP's `data.table`. They would have to be modified in order to accept single vectors.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi 15 cores. The difference is not as pronounced using `fastmatch`. There's a lot of overhead in passing the data back and forth.